# Watir installation issue

Tags: testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I am facing problem installing Watir. I've followed all the necessary steps given in **watirbook.pdf**. I've also installed the necessary extensions like **IEDriverServer** & **ChromeDriver** but i'm still having issues with both of the browsers, as shown below in screen capture.

[image]

It's completely working fine with **Firefox**.

Comment: Did you add the drivers to your PATH? If you just added them to your path, maybe try a reboot (on some systems, you have to reboot for the PATH changes to take effect).

Comment: Where should i add this drivers ?

Comment: You can put the drivers in any folder that is in your PATH. The [Watirbook](https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md) is quite detailed - see the [Chrome with watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md#chrome-with-watir-webdriver) section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin suggested you should download the IE driver/Chrome driver then extract the zip file and place the executable in your ruby path. In general the ruby path would be `C:\Ruby193\bin`.